# GraphQL Playground: How to set subscription connectionParams?

Tags: graphql, graphql-subscriptions, graphql-playground

I have a secure subscription endpoint on my apollo server. I can send subscription connectionParams from my react client by setting it in the WebSocketLink constructor and verify it in the onConnect property of ApolloServer constructor. But how do I test these subscriptions on GraphQL Playground? If I set the HTTP Headers on my subscriptions tab, it doesn't work. Is there any way to set this option in GQL playground?

Answer (score 0):

**connectionParams** can be passed using the **HTTP HEADERS** tab, at the bottom left corner of the graphql playground.

**Example:**
Let's say you wanted to pass the **authToken** parameter to your socket connection you could do it in the following way:

```
{
  "authToken": "sometoken"
}
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLcBv.png)